# letsencrypt shellinabox

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

I see this problem all over the internet searches, and can't seem to find the resolution.

I want to use shellinabox on whatever.net:54321

I have letsencrypt certificates

I've tried to copy /etc/letsencrypt/live/whatever.net/fullchain.pem to /var/libshellinabox/certificate.pem then chown shellinabox:shellinabox certificate.pem, but after trying to connect from a browser, SIAB creates a self-signed certificate-whatever.net.pem

I've also tried editing /etc/default/shellinabox certdir line to point to /etc/letsencrypt/live/whatever.net, but then shellinabox compains about not having correct file permissions. (Understandably so)

I've also tried copying /etc/letsencrypt/live/whatever.net/fullchain.pem to certificate.pem, and chown certificate.pem to shellinabox, but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Seems like it should be easy enough, but no matter what I've tried, letsencrypt still wants to make it's own self-signed certificates, which causes browsers to complain.

So, the big question, what's the magic tapdance to make siab use letsencyrypt certificates and stop making self-signed certificates?

Comment: From the [man page](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox/wiki/shellinaboxd_man): '`-c | --cert=certdir` : If built with SSL/TLS support enabled, the daemon will look in certdir for any certificates'.Have you tried this?

Comment: Of course... and I even said that I've done so in the post above.  See 5th "paragraph."  What happens when you do that (at least on debian) is 1) the directory permissions aren't correct for SIAB's liking and 2) certbot doesn't create the filename SIAB wants. 4th and 6th paragraphs cover that.  Please don't simply respond with RTFM when the issue is a major issue that appears in dead threads all over the internet.

Comment: Sorry; I was thinking from a different perspective, so the /etc/default thing went over my head. That said, you mentioned a permission error for the Let's Encrypt directory. Have you tried copying over the keys/certs to another directory with the permissions and names expected by shellinaboxd? If that works, you could write a script that bridges this gap between certbot and shellinaboxd.

Answer (score 1):

Shellinabox needed special combined certfile with name "/var/lib/shellinabox/certificate-*domain.name*.pem

```
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/privkey.pem \
                                        > /var/lib/shellinabox/certificate-domain.name.pem
```

Testing in Debian 11:

```
systemctl stop shellinabox.serivce 
shellinaboxd -v
```

For more detail, see this [link](https://gist.github.com/cjmatta/c3213b25af4a963b183def2a2a7c109a)

Comment: For more detail, see ... what?

Comment: added lost link to post